# How to read/write from/to a file using Go

Tags: file, go

I've been trying to learn Go on my own, but I've been stumped on trying read from and write to ordinary files.

I can get as far as `inFile, _ := os.Open(INFILE, 0, 0)`, but actually getting the content of the file doesn't make sense, because the read function takes a `[]byte` as a parameter.

```
func (file *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err Error)
```

Answer (score 574, accepted):

Let's make a Go 1-compatible list of all the ways to read and write files in Go.

Because file API has changed recently and most other answers don't work with Go 1. They also miss `bufio` which is important IMHO.

In the following examples I copy a file by reading from it and writing to the destination file.

**Start with the basics**

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // open input file
    fi, err := os.Open("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // close fi on exit and check for its returned error
    defer func() {
        if err := fi.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    // open output file
    fo, err := os.Create("output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // close fo on exit and check for its returned error
    defer func() {
        if err := fo.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    // make a buffer to keep chunks that are read
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        // read a chunk
        n, err := fi.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        // write a chunk
        if _, err := fo.Write(buf[:n]); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used `os.Open` and `os.Create` which are convenient wrappers around `os.OpenFile`. We usually don't need to call `OpenFile` directly.

Notice treating EOF. `Read` tries to fill `buf` on each call, and returns `io.EOF` as error if it reaches end of file in doing so. In this case `buf` will still hold data. Consequent calls to `Read` returns zero as the number of bytes read and same `io.EOF` as error. Any other error will lead to a panic.

**Using `bufio`**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // open input file
    fi, err := os.Open("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // close fi on exit and check for its returned error
    defer func() {
        if err := fi.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    // make a read buffer
    r := bufio.NewReader(fi)

    // open output file
    fo, err := os.Create("output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // close fo on exit and check for its returned error
    defer func() {
        if err := fo.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    // make a write buffer
    w := bufio.NewWriter(fo)

    // make a buffer to keep chunks that are read
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        // read a chunk
        n, err := r.Read(buf)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
        if n == 0 {
            break
        }

        // write a chunk
        if _, err := w.Write(buf[:n]); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    if err = w.Flush(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

`bufio` is just acting as a buffer here, because we don't have much to do with data. In most other situations (specially with text files) `bufio` is very useful by giving us [a nice API](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/bufio/) for reading and writing easily and flexibly, while it handles buffering behind the scenes.

---

**Note:** The following code is for older Go versions (Go 1.15 and before). Things have changed (`ioutil` is [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil) since Go 1.16). For the new way, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65970451/115363).

**Using `ioutil`**

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    // read the whole file at once
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // write the whole body at once
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("output.txt", b, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Easy as pie! But use it only if you're sure you're not dealing with big files.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this question, it was originally asked in 2009 before these libraries were introduced, so please, use this answer as your guide!

Comment: According to http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write, when Write hasn't written all bytes, it returns an error. So the extra check in the first example (`panic("error in writing")`) isn't necessary.

Comment: Note that these examples aren't checking the error return from fo.Close().  From the Linux man pages close(2): Not checking the return value of close() is a common  but  nevertheless serious  programming error.  It is quite possible that errors on a previous write(2) operation are first reported at the final close(). Not checking the return value when closing the file may lead to silent loss of data.  This can especially be observed with NFS and with disk quota.

Comment: @ayke Nice catch. I updated the answer (and some of my own code!) and removed the useless error check.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood Thank your for your important tip. I added extra code to check for error on calling `Close`. I’m also starting to check for error on `Close` in my own programs.

Comment: With the bufio example, the compiler complains that n2 is declared but not used.

Comment: @cdf Sorry for the bug. It was introduced in the last edit. Updated the answer to fix this.

Comment: Learning go here too. Shouldn't the defer code be the following: defer func() { if err := file.close(); err != nil { panic(err) } }()

Comment: My above error handling of close make only sense when one is writing to the file. When the file is opened for read only access, defer file.close() is all we need.

Comment: @chmike Thanks for catching that `err` bug. Fixed it. I was not sure about closing read-only files. Do you have any reference that says we should not worry about close errors for read-only files?

Comment: I deduced it from @NickCraig-Wood's comment, but indeed we should verify it every time to write bullet proof code.

Comment: So, what's a "big" file? 1KB? 1MB? 1GB? Or does "big" depend on the machine's hardware?

Comment: An important difference between os.File.Read() and bufio.Reader.Read() is when they can return fewer bytes than requested. The former will always try to fill the buffer, and only fille it with less bytes when it hits the EOF. While the latter, may fill with less bytes than the []byte can hold, and still not be serving up an EOF err yet.

Comment: @425nesp It reads whole the file into the memory, so it depends on the amount of available memory in the running machine.

Comment: What is "0644" in the WriteFile call?

Comment: @ebrts It defines the permissions of the file. You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Comment: You should probably `break` on `io.EOF` explicitly, since - according to the documentation - `n==0` doesn't always signify end of file

From the `Reader` interface source:

`// Implementations of Read are discouraged from returning a
// zero byte count with a nil error, except when len(p) == 0.
// Callers should treat a return of 0 and nil as indicating that
// nothing happened; in particular it does not indicate EOF.`

Comment: Isn't closing a file makes it flush the data? `w.Flush(...)` looks useless here.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood SO what do you do if and when ```File.Close``` returns an error? Do you delete the file? What it that fails?

Comment: Should be noted that `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` are now part of the `os` package.

Answer (score 58):

This is a good version (but do note that `ioutil` is [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil) since Go 1.16):

```
package main

import (
  "io/ioutil"; 
  )


func main() {
  contents,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("plikTekstowy.txt")
  println(string(contents))
  ioutil.WriteFile("filename", contents, 0644)
}
```

Comment: This stores the whole file in memory. Since the file can be large, that may not be always what you want to do.

Comment: Also, `0x777` is bogus.  In any case, it should be more like `0644` or `0755` (octal, not hex).

Comment: @cnst changed it to 0644 from 0x777

Comment: [Since the file already exists, `WriteFile` doesn't change permissions](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#WriteFile)

Answer (score 50):

#### New Way

Starting with Go 1.16, use [os.ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile) to load the file into memory, and use `os.WriteFile` to write to a file from memory ([ioutil.ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#ReadFile) now calls `os.ReadFile` and is deprecated).

Be careful with the `os.ReadFile` because it reads the whole file into memory.

```
package main

import "os"
import "log"

func main() {
    b, err := os.ReadFile("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // `b` contains everything your file has.
    // This writes it to the Standard Out.
    os.Stdout.Write(b)

    // You can also write it to a file as a whole.
    err = os.WriteFile("destination.txt", b, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have a 20GB file with 16GB of ram? 

Comment: One option is to use `io.Copy` and stream.

Answer (score 45):

**Using `io.Copy`**

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main () {
    // open files r and w
    r, err := os.Open("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer r.Close()

    w, err := os.Create("output.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer w.Close()

    // do the actual work
    n, err := io.Copy(w, r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Copied %v bytes\n", n)
}
```

If you don't feel like reinventing the wheel, the `io.Copy` and `io.CopyN` may serve you well. If you [check the source](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20/src/io/io.go#385) of the io.Copy function, it is nothing but one of the Mostafa's solutions (the 'basic' one, actually) packaged in the Go library. They are using a significantly larger buffer than he is, though.

Comment: one thing worth to mention - to be sure that the content of the file was written to disk, you need to use `w.Sync()` after the `io.Copy(w, r)`

Comment: Also, if you write to already existing file, `io.Copy()` will only write the data you feed it with, so if existing file had more content, it won't be removed, which may result in corrupted file.

Comment: @Invidian It all depends on how you open the destination file. If you do `w, err := os.Create("output.txt")`, what you describe does not happen, because "Create creates or truncates the named file. If the file already exists, it is truncated." https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it doesn't re-invent the wheel while not having to read the entire file at once before reading it.

Comment: @ShayTsadok Isn't closing the file will sync the data?

Comment: @x-yuri No, it won't, see the man page quotation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705454/does-linux-guarantee-the-contents-of-a-file-is-flushed-to-disc-after-close. This is the notorious Linux gotcha: put file to USB drive, pull out the USB drive, and only lean afterwards that the file was not written... That's why on Linux, if you write anything to USB drive, you _have to_ explicitly unmount.

Answer (score 23):

Note. `ioutil` is [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil) since Go 1.16.

With newer Go versions, reading/writing to/from a file is easy. To read from a file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("text.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

To write to a file:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("text.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    file.WriteString("test\nhello")
}
```

This will overwrite the content of a file (create a new file if it was not there).

Answer (score 10):

`[]byte` is a slice (similar to a substring) of all or part of a byte array. Think of the slice as a value structure with a hidden pointer field for the system to locate and access all or part of an array (the slice), plus fields for the length and capacity of the slice, which you can access using the `len()` and `cap()` functions.

Here's a working starter kit for you, which reads and prints a binary file; you will need to change the `inName` literal value to refer to a small file on your system.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt";
    "os";
)
func main()
{
    inName := "file-rw.bin";
    inPerm :=  0666;
    inFile, inErr := os.Open(inName, os.O_RDONLY, inPerm);
    if inErr == nil {
        inBufLen := 16;
        inBuf := make([]byte, inBufLen);
        n, inErr := inFile.Read(inBuf);
        for inErr == nil {
            fmt.Println(n, inBuf[0:n]);
            n, inErr = inFile.Read(inBuf);
        }
    }
    inErr = inFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: The Go convention is to check for error first, and let the normal code reside outside the `if` block

Comment: @Jurily: If the file is open when the error occurs, how do you close it?

Comment: But why is a [256]byte not accepted and the clearly silly and verbose (but apparently not wrong) inBuf:=make([]byte, 256) accepted?

Answer (score 8):

Note. Since Go 1.16 `ReadFile` is in the [`os` package](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile).

Try this:

```
package main

import (
  "io"; 
  )
  

func main() {
  contents,_ := io.ReadFile("filename");
  println(string(contents));
  io.WriteFile("filename", contents, 0644);
}
```

Comment: This will work if you want to read the whole file at once. If the file's really big or you only want to read part of it, it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: You should really check the error code, and not ignore it like that!!

Comment: This has been moved into the ioutil package now.  So it would be ioutil.ReadFile()

Comment: I fixed so it says 0644

Comment: It seems it was moved again to the [`os`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile) package.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `fmt` package also:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    file, err := os.Create("demo.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    
    fmt.Fprint(file, name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the documentation it seems you should just declare a buffer of type []byte and pass it to read which will then read up to that many characters and return the number of characters actually read (and an error).

[The docs](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Read) say

> Read reads up to len(b) bytes from the File. It returns the number of bytes read and an Error, if any. EOF is signaled by a zero count with err set to EOF.

Does that not work?

EDIT: Also, I think you should perhaps use the Reader/Writer interfaces declared in the *bufio* package instead of using *os* package.

Comment: You have my vote because you actually acknowledge what real people see when they read the documentation, instead of parrotting what those accustomed to Go are REMINDED OF (not reading REMINDED OF) when they read the documentation of the function they are familiar with already.

Answer (score 1):

The Read method takes a byte parameter because that is the buffer it will read into. It's a common *idiom* in some circles and makes some sense when you think about it.

This way you can determine how many bytes will be read by the reader and inspect the return to see how many bytes actually were read and handle any errors appropriately.

As others have pointed in their answers, bufio is probably what you want for reading from most files.

I'll add one other hint since it's really useful. Reading a line from a file is best accomplished not by the ReadLine method, but the ReadBytes or ReadString method instead.

Answer (score 0):

ioutil.WriteFile and ReadFile are deprecated in Go 1.16.Even I could not find these methods in io package. I found those methods in os package.
Following latest code works well.

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    os.WriteFile("sample.txt", []byte("Hello World"), 0666) //Writing file
    byteValue, _ := os.ReadFile("sample.txt")               //Reading file
    print(string(byteValue))
}
```

Comment: Just a note... if you have the tooling configured for your code editor, the warning that `ioutil.ReadFile` is deprecated also includes a recommendation of what function to use instead, in this case `os.ReadFile`