# How to read a binary file in Go

Tags: file-io, go

I'm completely new to Go and I'm trying to read a binary file, either byte by byte or several bytes at a time. The documentation doesn't help much and I cannot find any tutorial or simple example (by the way, how could Google give their language such an un-googlable name?). Basically, how can I open a file, then read some bytes into a buffer? Any suggestion?

Comment: It helps to use the term `golang` to search google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file

Comment: You might find this link useful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For manipulating files, the `os` package is your friend:

```
f, err := os.Open("myfile")
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
```

For more control over how the file is open, see `os.OpenFile()` instead [(doc)](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile).

For reading files, there are many ways. The `os.File` type returned by `os.Open` (the `f` in the above example) implements the `io.Reader` interface (it has a `Read()` method with the right signature), it can be used directly to read some data in a buffer (a `[]byte`) or it can also be wrapped in a buffered reader (type `bufio.Reader`).

Specifically for binary data, the `encoding/binary` package can be useful, to read a sequence of bytes into some typed structure of data. You can see an example in the [Go doc here](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read). The `binary.Read()` function can be used with the file read using the `os.Open()` function, since as I mentioned, it is a `io.Reader`.

And there's also the simple to use `io/ioutil` package, that allows you to read the whole file at once in a byte slice (`ioutil.ReadFile()`, which takes a file name, so you don't even have to open/close the file yourself), or `ioutil.ReadAll()` which takes a `io.Reader` and returns a slice of bytes containing the whole file. Here's the [doc on ioutil](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll).

Finally, as others mentioned, you can google about the Go language using "golang" and you should find all you need. The [golang-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) is also a great place to look for answers (make sure to search first before posting, a lot of stuff has already been answered). To look for third-party packages, check the [godoc.org](http://godoc.org/) website.

HTH

Comment: As of Go 1.16, `ioutil.ReadFile` is [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#ReadFile). Use `os.ReadFile`.

Answer (score 19):

This is what I use to read an entire binary file into memory

```
func RetrieveROM(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    stats, statsErr := file.Stat()
    if statsErr != nil {
        return nil, statsErr
    }

    var size int64 = stats.Size()
    bytes := make([]byte, size)

    bufr := bufio.NewReader(file)
    _,err = bufr.Read(bytes)

    return bytes, err
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `func ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error)` from the Go `io/ioutil` package?

Comment: @djhworld funny, I'm writing an emulator in Go at the moment and I stumbled across your answer after googling about binary files ;)

Comment: I recommend not using `bytes` as name for the `[]byte` because this is a library's name as well, maybe putting some other name will be better idea, like `byteArray` or something like that, other than that, this works fine.

Answer (score 10):

For example, to count the number of zero bytes in a file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("filename")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    data := make([]byte, 4096)
    zeroes := 0
    for {
        data = data[:cap(data)]
        n, err := f.Read(data)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        data = data[:n]
        for _, b := range data {
            if b == 0 {
                zeroes++
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("zeroes:", zeroes)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't whimsically cast primitive types to (char*) like in C, so for any sort of (de)serializing of binary data use the encoding/binary package.
http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary .
I can't improve on the examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `Read` method:

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   f, e := os.Open("a.go")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   for {
      b := make([]byte, 10)
      _, e = f.Read(b)
      if e == io.EOF {
         break
      } else if e != nil {
         panic(e)
      }
      // do something here
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.Read