# Why is ioutil.ReadFile() hanging after being called in a for loop?

Tags: image, file, go, io

I wrote a function that converts an image to a base64 string:

```
func getBase64Screenshot() string {
    // Image name
    imageName := "Screenshots/screenshot.png"

    imageFileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(imageName)
    handleError(err)

    // Converts file to base64 string
    encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imageFileBytes)

    return encoded
}
```

The above function is called in a `for loop`, however after some iterations of the for loop, the program just hangs at the line `imageFileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(imageName)` (it doesn't throw an error, it just stops running and stalls).

I ran some experiments and found that if I used a smaller image, it would make it through ~5 iterations of the `for loop` before stalling, however if I screenshot my entire screen it would only make it through the first iteration of the `for loop` before stalling.

My question is this: **What is causing the program to hang, and is there anything I can do to prevent it from hanging?**

Thanks!

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @A.R I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: Try my code and let me know if it works for you too

Answer (score 2):

Debug your code.

---

Try this and let me know if this works for you too:
This works like a charm for me on Linux:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(getBase64Screenshot()[:10])
    }
}
func getBase64Screenshot() string {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[0])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
    return encoded
}
```

Output:

```
time go run main.go
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ

real    0m0.340s
user    0m0.369s
sys     0m0.128s
```

Comment: This works, I get the following output:
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ
f0VMRgIBAQ

real 0m0.320s
user 0m0.369s
sys 0m0.074s

Comment: It's hard to format but the output is the exact same as yours, except the times are different

Comment: 'ioutil.ReadFile' uses `f, err := os.Open(filename)` then `f.Stat()` my recommendation for now is to read binary file byte by byte by yourself to find out the source of delay in reading file : use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571779/8208215)

Comment: Okay I'll try it out

Comment: I was able to fix the problem I was having (see my answer), looks like the issue is related to running the function above at regular intervals inside of a single goroutine

Comment: @Ash Hi, Again. Happy you solved it. for the sake of experience you better find out why. and you didn't post enough of  your old code so we could help. your question has not enough information to find that bug. and still your answer not makes sense that, what was that bug and how you solved it. it is better you make minimum code that creates that bug and then find that problem, you may edit your post and add to the end of it as a new `Edit: ...`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to debug the issue is to send a SIGABRT to your running program (when hanging) in order to [causes the program to exit with a stack dump](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#hdr-Default_behavior_of_signals_in_Go_programs).

```
kill -ABRT <pid>
# or CTRL+Pause on Windows.
```

Then you will see *where* the program is hang, and if it is actually related to your function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I was able to fix the issue.

You see, initially the function `getBase64Screenshot()` that I wrote above was being called every 10 seconds inside of a `goroutine`.

To fix the issue I refactored my code to eliminate the `goroutine` and instead call `getBase64Screenshot()` inside of an infinite loop:

```
for {
        getBase64Screenshot()
        time.Sleep(timedelayMilliseconds * time.Millisecond)
    }
```

I've tested the above code by running it for over 30 minutes with very large screenshots (>1MB in size), and it has **never crashed or stalled**.

Though I've fixed the issue I encountered, I haven't been able to figure out what exactly caused it in the first place. I welcome any theories as to why my original code above stalled.

Comment: How did you solve that bug? do you changed `getBase64Screenshot` function? In this form this is not an answer. you need to point that what was the source of bug, to make sense.