# How to write to a file in Go

Tags: file-io, go

I have seen [How to read/write from/to file using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1821811/984260) and http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write but could not get answer.

Is there a way, I can directly write an array of float/int to a file. Or do I have to change it to byte/string to write it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question has little sense as is, because it's not about writing a file but rather about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). As others pointed out, Go has several ways to implement this using its standard packages, but it worth grasping the general concept as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the functions in the [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package for this purpose.

As far as writing an entire array at once goes, there are no functions for this. You will have to iterate the array and write each element individually. Ideally, you should prefix these elements with a single integer, denoting the length of the array.

If you want a higher level solution, you can try the [encoding/gob](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package:

> Package gob manages streams of gobs - binary values exchanged between an Encoder (transmitter) and a Decoder (receiver). A typical use is transporting arguments and results of remote procedure calls (RPCs) such as those provided by package "rpc".

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find a useful one, since they take buf as input and return int. But I think to use the os.File functions, I need to change from int/float to buf.

Comment: I solved it by converting int to string and then writing. Thanks.

Comment: user984260: These functions take an `io.Reader` or `io.Writer` interface as input. This is an interface type. Any object which satisfies this interface can be used. This includes the `*os.File` structure. For instance: `binary.Write(w io.Writer, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error`. The first argument (`w`) can be your file handle.