# Golang: write []int to file

Tags: file, go, slice

I have some data in  `p []int`, I want to save/load it to/from file. Should i convert this slice to `[]byte` and use (if yes, how?)

```
func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err Error)
func (f *File) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

or there are other way to save `[]int` to file?

I read this [How to read/write from/to file using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file), and it didn't help.

Comment: How do you want the data to be stored?  If it is binary, should it be big or little endian?  The `int` type has different size on different platforms, so what precision should be stored?

Comment: It's not important how data be stored, i want to save it, restart app, and get the same data in RAM. I want to store `[]int32`.

Comment: @Sam, no you can't say it's not important: data in memory is, on the one hand, is an abstract concept (in Go, you work with `int`s which might have different representation from one hardware platform to another), on the other hand, data on a storage medium *has to* have certain format.  And it's you who decides which exactly. This might be a JSON file, XML file, a database, a plain binary file with custom format, a plain text file with custom format -- the possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If interchanging the format (between languages other than go) or reading it as a stream is not important to you, just use the `gob` encoder and decoder.

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/

The idea is that you create an encoder around a writer, or a decoder around a reader, and then just ask them to encode or decode a struct. Encoding goes something like this:

```
p := []int{1,2,3,4}

encoder := gob.NewEncoder(myFileWriter)
err = encoder.Encode(p)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

decoding works just the opposite way:

```
decoder := gob.NewDecoder(myFileReader)
p := []int{}

err = decoder.Decode(&p)
if err != nil {
         panic(err)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use similar methods available in the standard library, for storing the data as JSON or XML, which allow you more easily to debug things, and open the data from other languages (at the cost of size and efficiency).

Comment: if format interchange between languages is import? :) What would be the approach to this.

Comment: @Roylee json would be the simplest solution. but there are many.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
file.WriteString(fmt.Sprintln(p))
```

a complete example:

```
    /*path of the file test.txt : you have to change it*/
var path = "/Users/Pippo/workspace/Go/src/......./test.txt"

func main() {

    p := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 99}
    fmt.Println(p)
    createFile()
    writeFile(p)

}

/*create file*/
func createFile() {

    // detect if file exists
    var _, err = os.Stat(path)

    // create file if not exists
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        var file, err = os.Create(path)
        if isError(err) {
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
    }

    fmt.Println("==> done creating file", path)
}



/* print errors*/
func isError(err error) bool {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return (err != nil)
}

/*writeFile write the data into file*/
func writeFile(p []int) {

    // open file using READ & WRITE permission
    var file, err = os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR, 0644)

    if isError(err) {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // write into file
    _, err = file.WriteString(fmt.Sprintln(p))
    if isError(err) {
        return
    }

    // save changes
    err = file.Sync()
    if isError(err) {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("==> done writing to file")
}
```