# Convert back byte array into file using golang

Tags: file, go, decode

Is there a way to write a byte array to a file? I have the file name and file extension(like temp.xml).

Comment: [How to read/write from/to file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds like you just want the `ioutil.WriteFile` function from the standard library.

https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile

It would look something like this:

```
permissions := 0644 // or whatever you need
byteArray := []byte("to be written to a file\n")
err := ioutil.WriteFile("file.txt", byteArray, permissions)
if err != nil { 
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: ioutil.WriteFile() has been replaced by os.WriteFile, and permissions are no longer an int, and can be passed in directly as the octal code. E.g.`err = os.WriteFile("file.txt", byteArray, 0666)`

Answer (score 3):

According to https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile, as of Go 1.16 this function is deprecated. Use https://pkg.go.dev/os#WriteFile instead (`ioutil.WriteFile` simply calls `os.WriteFile` as of 1.16).

Otherwise, [Jeffrey Martinez's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29703/jeffrey-martinez) answer remains correct:

```golang
permissions := 0644 // or whatever you need
byteArray := []byte("to be written to a file\n")
err := os.WriteFile("file.txt", byteArray, permissions)
if err != nil { 
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: I believe permissions would be assigned an int type which would throw an error when passed to os.WriteFile() (which expects perms to be an fs.FileMode). Permissions are now stated directly in the function call.