# How to covert a []byte object to an image and store it as a jpeg image on disk

Tags: image, go, jpeg

I am trying to convert an []byte object to an image and save it as a jpeg in Golang. I tried to use `Decode` function of image but it always returns `<nil>`.

```
func saveFrames(imgByte []byte) {
    img, _, _ := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imgByte))
   out, err := os.Create("./img.jpeg")

   if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err)
             os.Exit(1)
   }
   err = jpeg.Encode(out, img)
   if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/write from/to file using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821811/how-to-read-write-from-to-file-using-go)

Comment: Check your errors. Always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not passing `Options`,to `jpeg.Encode`, you can also set it to nil.

```
func serveFrames(imgByte []byte) {

    img, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewReader(imgByte))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    out, _ := os.Create("./img.jpeg")
    defer out.Close()

    var opts jpeg.Options
    opts.Quality = 1

    err = jpeg.Encode(out, img, &opts)
    //jpeg.Encode(out, img, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Don't forget to close any file, if opened.

You can use `log.Fatalln(...)`, if you want to print error message and quit in-case of any error.

Comment: 2018/10/23 14:03:42 invalid JPEG format: short Huffman data
Getting this error:

Comment: @shahidammer, data in `imgByte` should data of some image

Comment: Quality 1? Even 100 looks terrible. Isn't there a better way which doesn't play with quality? Or does it depend on bytes?

Answer (score 0):

guess this is what u really want:

```
err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, bt, 0644)
```