# File is not written on disk until program ends

Tags: c, unix

I'm writing a file using a c code on a unix system . I open it , write a few lines and close it. Then i call a shell script, say code B where this file is to be used and then return back to main program. However, when code B tries to read the file, the file is empty.

I checked  the file on the file system, its size is shown as 0 and no data is present in file. However after killing the running c code process, file has data present in it.

Here is the piece of code -

```
void writefile(){
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("ABC.txt","w");
  fputs("Some lines...\n",fp);
  fclose(fp);

  system("code_B ABC.txt");
}
```

Please advise how can I read the file in the shell script without stopping the c code process.

Comment: Which file system are you using? Is this a local disc, or a network file system?

Comment: the system is in a storage area network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's some time between the fputs and fclose, add

```
fflush(fp);
```

This will cause the contents of the disk file to be written.

Comment: Should this not be done by the `fclose()` call? http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose: `The fclose() function flushes the stream pointed to by fp (writing any buffered output data using fflush(3))`

Comment: Yes, but I suspect the actual code may not be as described.

Comment: +1 since that obviously fixed OPs issue - not sure why, yet ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should do fsync() after the fclose(), to guarantee the writing of the file to the disk.

Take a look at this question:

[Does Linux guarantee the contents of a file is flushed to disc after close()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705454/does-linux-guarantee-the-contents-of-a-file-is-flushed-to-disc-after-close)

Comment: Still, the contents should also be `read` from the buffers afterwards, even if the content is not **physically** written to disc yet - the kernel / file system should ensure that

Answer (score 3):

The kernel ensures that data which is written to a file can be read back afterwards from a different process, even if it is not **physically** written to the disc yet. So, in usual scenarios, there is no need to call `fsync()` - still, even with `fsync()`, the filesystem could decide to further delay physical writes.

One common problem is that the C library has not flushed its buffers yet, in which case you would need to call `fflush()` - however, you are calling `fclose()` before launching your sub process, and `fclose()` internally calls `fflush()`.

Actually, since `system()` is using a shell to launch the command passed as parameter, you can use the following simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to verify that it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writefile(){
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("ABC.txt","w");
  fputs("Some lines...\n",fp);
  fclose(fp);

  system("cat ABC.txt");
}

int main() {
  writefile();
  return 0;
}
```

Here, `system()` simply calls the `cat` command to print the file contents. The output is:

```
$ ./writefile
Some lines...
```

Comment: I tried the same , but it doesn't work. I called fsync() after fcolse() but to no avail. The files content are still not reflected till the process ends.

Comment: Finally issue is resolved. Calling `fflush()`  before `fclose()` did the trick.

Comment: That is interesting. Which compiler version and which C runtime library version are you using, and on which platform/operating system version? Btw, you should accept the answer from @MarkHarrison - obviously he was on the right track...