# Bash: writing to and appending to file using > operator

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash script, if I do  `echo "abc" > file.txt` or `echo "abc" >> file.tx` am I guaranteed that when the next line of the script is executed, `"abc"` is present in the `file.txt`?

clarification:
What I had in mind is whether I can be sure that after I do
`echo "some text" > file.txt` and proceed to the next line in my script and call some other process, also from my script, that reads `file.txt`, will that process read `"some text"` from the file?
Also, once I write to the file like that and terminate the script, does script termination perform the flush?

Comment: no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705454/does-linux-guarantee-the-contents-of-a-file-is-flushed-to-disc-after-close

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov That's not relevant. Even if the data is not flushed to disk, processes will still see the data as long as it is written out to the operating system (which > and >> both do)

Comment: The question is what does the OP mean by "is present in the `file.txt`" and how they expect to be checking that.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to find out? What do you mean "in the `file.txt`" exactly? How are you intending to be checking for it that you are worried about?

Comment: I gave links because it has excellent explanation about write cashing. Execution of the next line in shell script doesn't mean 'close'.  I can easily imagine  some write to the network mount and erroneous notification of the other host listener about data which was written.

Comment: Are there background processes involved? In the simple sequential case, if yours is the only process manipulating the file, you should be fine; but that's a precarious assumption.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a clarification.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov, the question doesn't ask for disk flushing, just for file contents at OS view.  The answer is just the opposite: yes.

Comment: Initial version of the question was more abstract. In the abstract form answer is simple: 'no'.  You can write to the network/distributed mount and you can't be sure that data was really modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer is *yes*.  If the process you have launched with output redirected has finished (for that, the shell just does a **wait(2)** system call) the complete process image has been eliminated from kernel internal tables and all file descriptors are closed (so it cannot do any more system calls).

In general, you cannot warrantee that a process is doing buffering in its user space or not.  The kernel warrants that, once a **write(2)** system call has been executed, the file contents seen by all the system's processes has that data included.  To achieve this, the kernel just blocks the inode image in the kernel memory to allow the process making the system call to write the in kernel allocated buffers and not be disturbed by other kernel activity that can happen at the same time.  This grants exclusive access to the file contents when a process is **read(2)** ing or **write(2)** ing. And the inode is blocked for the whole system call (to make the call atomic).  After it, all the file contents appear updated to other processes.

The inode locking while the process is writing is something that warrants that the write system call will be made completely before other things can happen, like:

- some other process is trying to write the same file.
- Some other process unlinks the open file (all processes with access to *this* file before unlinking will continue to have access to it, even if not present in the filesystem)  Even if some other process creates a file with the same name, all the write will go to the old, opened file.
- Some other process tries to read (it'll read the whole data written or not at all, but will not do a partial read)
- Some other process changes permissions on the file (the permissions to write a file are only checked at **open(2)** time).
- Some other process truncates the file.  This will be serialized in time, to make the write to happen before or after the system call (but not in the middle).
- Some other process tries to unmount the filesystem to which this file belongs to.

All these possibilities (and more) have to be contempled in kernel code to warrant the data is consistent.

As the process you are executing is finished, the answer is that all data written will be visible to other processes (it has been finshed, so it cannot make new (neither after **close(2)**, nor after **write(2)**) even if no data has been flushed to disk.

---

On the other side, the example you used doesn't fully apply in the explanation up to here: `echo` is normally an internal shell command, that is executed by the shell in it's user space.  As such, this could make things to happen differently, as the process that makes the system calls is the shell, and it has not **exit(2)** before the command.  But even in that case, the shell can spawn a new process just to execute this redirected command (instead of calling **exec(2)** to execute a different command), and it **exit(2)** s after executing it, so all file descriptors will be closed also.  This makes the example applicable here also.

In the case the shell doesn't spawn a new process for the command (there are also cases for this, at least in **bash(1)**) the behaviour is to appear as if a new process has been spawn, so the shell has the resposibility of properly **close(2)** the file descriptor, either.

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis for the detailed explanation

Comment: Putting the tick as the selected response would be a good thing then.

Answer (score 4):

Once the command which includes a redirection to `file.txt` terminates, anything written to stdout is present in `file.txt`, and will be seen by a subsequent process which reads `file.txt`.

But there are some caveats:

1. It's entirely possible for another simultaneously-executing process to delete or overwrite the file.
2. Unix/Linux does not guarantee that data written to a file will be committed to permanent storage immediately when the file is closed. [Note 1] So if the machine on which the file is stored crashes and is rebooted between writing and reading, it is possible that the reading task will not see data written before the crash.
3. If the writing task terminates abnormally, it is possible that it will not have flushed its output buffers to stdout. So if the task crashes, it is possible that nothing will have been written to the file.

In summary, it would be better to say that data written to a file in the course of a bash command (whether named directly or via a redirect) will be visible to subsequent commands as long as the first task terminated normally, no other running process is manipulating the same file, and the host does not crash before the subsequent command is executed.

---

#### Notes

1. Normally, it doesn't matter that the file is not immediately committed to permanent storage, because the OS must act as though pending modifications were present in the file. Furthermore, during normal shutdown, the OS will commit all pending filesystem modifications. However, if the host machine crashes, or there is some unrecoverable filesystem error on reboot, then it is possible that some filesystem modifications will be lost.

   All of the above applies to the machine on which the file is stored, which might be different from the machine from which the file was written and read in the case that the file is being accessed via a network filesystem.