# Calling fsync(2) after close(2)

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems, posix

Scenario:

Task code (error checking omitted):

```
// open, write and close
fd = open(name);
write(fd, buf, len);
close(fd);
< more code here **not** issuing read/writes to name but maybe open()ing it >
// open again and fsync
fd = open(name);
fsync(fd);
```

No more tasks accessing `name` concurrently in the system.

Is it defined, and more important, will it sync possible outstanding writes on the inode referred by `name`? ie, will I read back `buf` from the file after the fsync?

From POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html I would say it seems legit ...

Thanks.

Edit may 18:
Thanks for the answers and research. I took this question (in 2016) to one of the extfs lead developers (Ted) and got this answer: "It's not guaranteed by Posix, but in practice it should work on most
file systems, including ext4.  The key wording in the Posix specification is:

> The `fsync()` function shall request that all data **for the open file descriptor named by `fildes`** is to be transferred to the storage device associated with the file described by `fildes`.

It does not say "all data for the file described by `fildes`...."  it
says "all data for the open file descriptor".  So technically data
written by another file descriptor is not guaranteed to be synced to
disk.

In practice, file systems don't try dirty data by which fd it came in
on, so you don't need to worry.  And an OS which writes more than what
is strictly required is standards compliant, and so that's what you
will find in general, even if it isn't guaranteed."  This is less specific than "exact same durabily guarrantees" but is quite authoritative, even though maybe outdated.

What I was trying to do was a 'sync' command that worked on single files.
Like fsync /some/file without having to sync the whole filesystem, to use it in shell scripts for example.
Now (since a few years ago) gnu coreutils 'sync' works on single files and does exactly this (open/fsync). commit: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/8b2bf5295f353016d4f5e6a2317d55b6a8e7fd00

Comment: Since you just opened the file descriptor, there is no "data for the open file descriptor named by fildes is to be transferred", so I would say no.

Comment: @marcolz that is my doubt. But I would say that pending requests on the inode referred by `filedes` are "data for the open file descriptor"

Comment: [This comment](https://lwn.net/Articles/323035/) suggests that you can _write "a bunch of files you can write them all without fsync, then go back and reopen/fsync them"_, suggesting that fsync after close works. It would make sense this way -- otherwise after close() there'd be no way to ever force data to be written to disk. But It would be great to get an authorative answer on this. I've started a bounty.

Comment: I have asked this question on `linux-fsdevel`. I [got confirmed](https://marc.info/?l=linux-fsdevel&m=152535409207496&w=2) that at least as of writing, `close()/re-open()/fsync()` does **not** provide the same guarantees as `fsync()/close()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, `close()`+re-`open()`+`fsync()` does not provide the same guarantees as `fsync()`+`close()`.

Source: I [took this question](https://marc.info/?l=linux-fsdevel&m=152535098505449&w=2) to the `linux-fsdevel` mailing list and [got the answer](https://marc.info/?l=linux-fsdevel&m=152535409207496&w=2):

> > Does a sequence of close()/re-open()/fsync() provide the same durability
> >     guarantees as fsync()/close()?
>
> The short answer is no, the latter provides a better guaranty.
>   The longer answer is that durability guarantees depends on kernel version,
>   because situation has been changing in v4.13, v4.14 and now again in
>   v4.17-rc and stable kernels.

Further relevant links are:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fsync_Errors ("fsyncgate")
- Mailing list entry [PostgreSQL's handling of fsync() errors is unsafe and risks data loss at least on XFS](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMsr%2BYHh%2B5Oq4xziwwoEfhoTZgr07vdGG%2Bhu%3D1adXx59aTeaoQ%40mail.gmail.com#CAMsr+YHh+5Oq4xziwwoEfhoTZgr07vdGG+hu=1adXx59aTeaoQ@mail.gmail.com)
- [Writing programs to cope with I/O errors causing lost writes on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434872/writing-programs-to-cope-with-i-o-errors-causing-lost-writes-on-linux) from the same author

In particular, the latter links describe how

- after closing an FD, you lose all ways to enforce durability
- after an `fsync()` fails, you cannot call `fsync()` again in the hope that now your data would be written
- you [must re-do/confirm all writing work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434872/writing-programs-to-cope-with-i-o-errors-causing-lost-writes-on-linux#comment72017184_42436401) if that happens

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated my question with some info.

Answer (score 4):

The current (2017) specification of POSIX [`fsync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html)
recognizes a base functionality and an optional functionality:

> The `fsync()` function shall request that all data for the open file descriptor named by `fildes` is to be transferred to the storage device associated with the file described by `fildes`. The nature of the transfer is implementation-defined. The `fsync()` function shall not return until the system has completed that action or until an error is detected.
>
> [SIO] ⌦ If `_POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO` is defined, the `fsync()` function shall force all currently queued I/O operations associated with the file indicated by file descriptor `fildes` to the synchronized I/O completion state. All I/O operations shall be completed as defined for synchronized I/O file integrity completion. ⌫

If `_POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO` is not defined by the implementation, then your reopened file descriptor has no unwritten data to be transferred to the storage device, so the `fsync()` call is effectively a no-op.

If `_POSIX_SYNCHRONIZED_IO` is defined by the implementation, then your reopened file descriptor will ensure that all data written on any file descriptor associated with the file to be transferred to the storage device.

The section of the standard on [Conformance](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html) has information about options and option groups.
The [Definitions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) section has definitions [382..387](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_382) which defines aspects of Synchronized I/O and Synchronous I/O (yes, they're different — beware open file descriptors and open file descriptions, too).
The section on [Realtime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08) defers to the Definitions section for what synchronized I/O means.

It defines:

> #### 3.382 Synchronized Input and Output
>
> A determinism and robustness improvement mechanism to enhance the data input and output mechanisms, so that an application can ensure that the data being manipulated is physically present on secondary mass storage devices.
>
> #### 3.383 Synchronized I/O Completion
>
> The state of an I/O operation that has either been successfully transferred or diagnosed as unsuccessful.
>
> #### 3.384 Synchronized I/O Data Integrity Completion
>
> For read, when the operation has been completed or diagnosed if unsuccessful. The read is complete only when an image of the data has been successfully transferred to the requesting process. If there were any pending write requests affecting the data to be read at the time that the synchronized read operation was requested, these write requests are successfully transferred prior to reading the data.
>
> For write, when the operation has been completed or diagnosed if unsuccessful. The write is complete only when the data specified in the write request is successfully transferred and all file system information required to retrieve the data is successfully transferred.
>
> File attributes that are not necessary for data retrieval (access time, modification time, status change time) need not be successfully transferred prior to returning to the calling process.
>
> #### 3.385 Synchronized I/O File Integrity Completion
>
> Identical to a synchronized I/O data integrity completion with the addition that all file attributes relative to the I/O operation (including access time, modification time, status change time) are successfully transferred prior to returning to the calling process.
>
> #### 3.386 Synchronized I/O Operation
>
> An I/O operation performed on a file that provides the application assurance of the integrity of its data and files.
>
> #### 3.387 Synchronous I/O Operation
>
> An I/O operation that causes the thread requesting the I/O to be blocked from further use of the processor until that I/O operation completes.
>
> Note:
>   A synchronous I/O operation does not imply synchronized I/O data integrity completion or synchronized I/O file integrity completion.

It is not 100% clear whether the 'all currently queued I/O operations associated with the file indicated by [the] file descriptor' applies across processes.
Conceptually, I think it should, but the wording isn't there in black and white (or black on pale yellow).  It certainly should apply to any open file descriptors in the current process referring to the same file.  It is not clear that it would apply to the previously opened (and closed) file descriptor in the current process.  If it applies across all processes, then it should include the queued I/O from the current process.  If it does not apply across all processes, it is possible that it does not.

In view of this and the rationale notes for `fsync()`, it is by far safest to assume that the `fsync()` operation has no effect on the queued operations associated with the closed file descriptor.  If you want `fsync()` to be effective, call it before you close the file descriptor.