# Writing programs to cope with I/O errors causing lost writes on Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, posix

TL;DR: **If the Linux kernel loses a buffered I/O write**, is there any way for the application to find out?

**I know you have to `fsync()` the file (and its parent directory) for durability**. The question is *if the kernel loses dirty buffers that are pending write* due to an I/O error, how can the application detect this and recover or abort?

Think database applications, etc, where order of writes and write durability can be crucial.

### Lost writes? How?

The Linux kernel's block layer can under some circumstances *lose* buffered I/O requests that have been submitted successfully by `write()`, `pwrite()` etc, with an error like:

```
Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 12345
lost page write due to I/O error on dm-0
```

(See [`end_buffer_write_sync(...)` and `end_buffer_async_write(...)` in `fs/buffer.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/buffer.c?v=2.6.26#L445)).

[On newer kernels the error will instead contain "lost async page write"](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/buffer.c?v=4.9#L353), like:

```
Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 12345, lost async page write
```

Since the application's `write()` will have already returned without error, there seems to be no way to report an error back to the application.

### Detecting them?

I'm not that familiar with the kernel sources, but I *think* that it sets `AS_EIO` on the buffer that failed to be written-out if it's doing an async write:

```
    set_bit(AS_EIO, &page->mapping->flags);
    set_buffer_write_io_error(bh);
    clear_buffer_uptodate(bh);
    SetPageError(page);
```

but it's unclear to me if or how the application can find out about this when it later `fsync()`s the file to confirm it's on disk.

It looks like [`wait_on_page_writeback_range(...)` in `mm/filemap.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=2.6.26#L267) might by [`do_sync_mapping_range(...)` in `fs/sync.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sync.c?v=2.6.26#L250) which is turn called by [`sys_sync_file_range(...)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sync.c?v=2.6.26#L177). It returns `-EIO` if one or more buffers could not be written.

If, as I'm guessing, this propagates to `fsync()`'s result, then if the app panics and bails out if it gets an I/O error from `fsync()` and knows how to re-do its work when restarted, that should be sufficient safeguard?

There's presumably no way for the app to know *which* byte offsets in a file correspond to the lost pages so it can rewrite them if it knows how, but if the app repeats all its pending work since the last successful `fsync()` of the file, and that rewrites any dirty kernel buffers corresponding to lost writes against the file, that should clear any I/O error flags on the lost pages and allow the next `fsync()` to complete - right?

Are there then any other, harmless, circumstances where `fsync()` may return `-EIO` where bailing out and redoing work would be too drastic?

### Why?

Of course such errors should not happen. In this case the error arose from an unfortunate interaction between the `dm-multipath` driver's defaults and the sense code used by the SAN to report failure to allocate thin-provisioned storage. But this isn't the only circumstance where they *can* happen - I've also seen reports of it from thin provisioned LVM for example, as used by libvirt, Docker, and more. An critical application like a database should try to cope with such errors, rather than blindly carrying on as if all is well.

If the *kernel* thinks it's OK to lose writes without dying with a kernel panic, applications have to find a way to cope.

The practical impact is that I found a case where a multipath problem with a SAN caused lost writes that landed up causing database corruption because the DBMS didn't know its writes had failed. Not fun.

Comment: I'm afraid this would need additional fields in the SystemFileTable to store&remember these error conditions. And a possibility for the userspace process to receive or inspect them on subsequent calls. (do fsync() and close() return this kind of *historic* information?)

Comment: @joop Thanks. I just posted an answer with what I think is going on, mind having a sanity-check since you seem to know more about what's going on than the people who've posted obvious variants of "write() needs close() or fsync() for durability" without reading the question?

Comment: BTW: I think you really should delve into the kernel sources. The journalled filesystems would probably suffer from the same kind of problems. Not to mention the swap partition handling. Since these live in kernel space, the handling of these conditions will probably a bit more rigid. writev() , which is visible from userspace, also seems like a place to look. [ at Craig: yes becaus I know your name, and I know you are not a complete idiot ;-]

Comment: @joop Yeah, been source-spelunking for a couple of hours now. Love that a total kernel newbie can follow what's going on reasonably well, lovely clean sources. Currently trying to verify that `fsync()` in `glibc` is backed by the `sys_sync_file_range` syscall, in which case I'm pretty sure I know what's wrong now - and that the `fsync` man page badly needs a big fat warning added to it about retries.

Comment: My guess is that retry behaviour is different for internal kernel use and userspace. System usage should retry and panic, user space should (maybe retry and) but fail ASAP. Clearing the error flags inbetween requests does not seem right. Source quality: at least they don't cast malloc()s return value!  BTW there are of cource a lot of options for failure inside system. (such as umount the device, etc)

Comment: In case of critical application you just have to use `O_SYNC|O_DIRECT` combination at opening.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès If you don't mind the utterly abysmal performance that results. Synchronous writes are awful. You can't realistically do that in something like a DBMS unless you've gone Oracle-style and re-implemented half the kernel's I/O smarts in your DBMS, with dedicated writer threads, cache management, etc. In which case you might as well use AIO. You're trying to define the problem away by avoiding `fsync()` and buffered I/O entirely. My question is how you can use buffered I/O and `fsync()` correctly and safely.

Comment: Sure it would be terribly bad in performance, but it is a price to pay. If you want to read something about ensuring ACID properties for DBMS, you can read the following https://www.quora.com/How-do-RDBMS-provide-ACID-properties-atomicity-consistency-isolation-durability. Interesting questions are answered very simply.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I agree, good explanation. But again, somewhat off topic. I'm asking if *using buffered I/O* it is possible to detect and correctly cope with I/O errors where the kernel loses writes. I have answered this myself, below, after further research. Now, if I wanted to completely rewrite the DBMS to use AIO or a pool of threads with synchronous direct I/O or something, sure, I could follow your suggestion. But it should be possible and (per below) is possible to do it correctly with buffered I/O and careful use of fsync.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès By analogy, if I asked "how do I park a car" you've first explained "don't park the car, use a taxi so you don't have to" then "here's how parking regulations work". Both interesting, but not that relevant to the original problem.

Comment: I agree, I wasn't so fair. Alas your answer is not very satisfying, I mean there no easy solution (surprising?).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès True. For the DBMS I'm working with, "crash and enter redo" is acceptable. For most apps that's not an option and they might have to tolerate synchronous I/O's horrid performance or just accept poorly defined behaviour and corruption on I/O errors.

Answer (score 101):

### `fsync()` returns `-EIO` if the kernel lost a write

(Note: early part references older kernels; updated below to reflect modern kernels)

It looks like [async buffer write-out in `end_buffer_async_write(...)` failures set an `-EIO` flag on the failed dirty buffer page for the file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/buffer.c?v=2.6.26#L465):

```
set_bit(AS_EIO, &page->mapping->flags);
set_buffer_write_io_error(bh);
clear_buffer_uptodate(bh);
SetPageError(page);
```

which is then detected by `wait_on_page_writeback_range(...)` as called by `do_sync_mapping_range(...)` as called by `sys_sync_file_range(...)` as called by `sys_sync_file_range2(...)` to implement the C library call `fsync()`.

### But only once!

[This comment on  `sys_sync_file_range`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sync.c?v=2.6.26#L168)

```
168  * SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_BEFORE and SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_AFTER will detect any
169  * I/O errors or ENOSPC conditions and will return those to the caller, after
170  * clearing the EIO and ENOSPC flags in the address_space.
```

suggests that when `fsync()` returns `-EIO` or (undocumented in the manpage) `-ENOSPC`, it will *clear the error state* so a subsequent `fsync()` will report success even though the pages never got written.

Sure enough `wait_on_page_writeback_range(...)` [*clears the error bits when it tests them*](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=2.6.26#L301):

```
301         /* Check for outstanding write errors */
302         if (test_and_clear_bit(AS_ENOSPC, &mapping->flags))
303                 ret = -ENOSPC;
304         if (test_and_clear_bit(AS_EIO, &mapping->flags))
305                 ret = -EIO;
```

**So if the application expects it can re-try `fsync()` until it succeeds and trust that the data is on-disk, it is terribly wrong.**

I'm pretty sure this is the source of the data corruption I found in the DBMS. It retries `fsync()` and thinks all will be well when it succeeds.

### Is this allowed?

The [POSIX/SuS docs on `fsync()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html) don't really specify this either way:

> If the fsync() function fails, outstanding I/O operations are not guaranteed to have been completed.

[Linux's man-page for `fsync()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) just doesn't say anything about what happens on failure.

So it seems that the meaning of `fsync()` errors is "I don't know what happened to your writes, might've worked or not, better try again to be sure".

### Newer kernels

On 4.9 [`end_buffer_async_write`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/buffer.c?v=4.9#L340) sets `-EIO` on the page, just via `mapping_set_error`.

```
    buffer_io_error(bh, ", lost async page write");
    mapping_set_error(page->mapping, -EIO);
    set_buffer_write_io_error(bh);
    clear_buffer_uptodate(bh);
    SetPageError(page);
```

On the sync side I think it's similar, though the structure is now pretty complex to follow. `filemap_check_errors` in `mm/filemap.c` now does:

```
    if (test_bit(AS_EIO, &mapping->flags) &&
        test_and_clear_bit(AS_EIO, &mapping->flags))
            ret = -EIO;
```

which has much the same effect. Error checks seem to all go through [`filemap_check_errors`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=4.9#L346) which does a test-and-clear:

```
    if (test_bit(AS_EIO, &mapping->flags) &&
        test_and_clear_bit(AS_EIO, &mapping->flags))
            ret = -EIO;
    return ret;
```

I'm using `btrfs` on my laptop, but when I create an `ext4` loopback for testing on `/mnt/tmp` and set up a perf probe on it:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ext bs=1M count=100
sudo mke2fs -j -T ext4 /tmp/ext
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/ext /mnt/tmp

sudo perf probe filemap_check_errors

sudo perf record -g -e probe:end_buffer_async_write -e probe:filemap_check_errors dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/tmp/test bs=4k count=1 conv=fsync
```

I find the following call stack in `perf report -T`:

```
        ---__GI___libc_fsync
           entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath
           sys_fsync
           do_fsync
           vfs_fsync_range
           ext4_sync_file
           filemap_write_and_wait_range
           filemap_check_errors
```

A read-through suggests that yeah, modern kernels behave the same.

This seems to mean that if `fsync()` (or presumably `write()` or `close()`) returns `-EIO`, the file is in some undefined state between when you last successfully `fsync()`d or `close()`d it and its most recently `write()`ten state.

### Test

[I've implemented a test case to demonstrate this behaviour](https://github.com/ringerc/scrapcode/blob/master/testcases/fsync-error-clear.c).

### Implications

A DBMS can cope with this by entering crash recovery. How on earth is a normal user application supposed to cope with this? The `fsync()` man page gives no warning that it means "fsync-if-you-feel-like-it" and I expect a *lot* of apps won't cope well with this behaviour.

### Bug reports

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194755
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194757

### Further reading

[lwn.net touched on this in the article "Improved block-layer error handling"](https://lwn.net/Articles/724307/).

[postgresql.org mailing list thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMsr%2BYE5Gs9iPqw2mQ6OHt1aC5Qk5EuBFCyG%2BvzHun1EqMxyQg%40mail.gmail.com#CAMsr+YE5Gs9iPqw2mQ6OHt1aC5Qk5EuBFCyG+vzHun1EqMxyQg@mail.gmail.com).

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/buffer.c?v=2.6.26#L598 is a possible race, because it waits for {pending&scheduled I/O}, not for {not yet scheduled I/O}. This is obviously to avoid extra round-trips to the device. (I presume user writes() don't return until I/O is scheduled, for mmap(), this is different)

Comment: Is it possible that some other process's call to fsync for some other file on the same disk gets the error return?

Comment: @Random832 Very relevant for a multi-processing DB like PostgreSQL, so good question. Looks like probably, but I don't know the kernel code well enough to understand. Your procs had better be co-operating if they both have the same file open anyway though.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: The syscalls return failures using negative errno codes; `errno` is completely a construct of the userspace C library. It is common to ignore the return value differences between the syscalls and the C library like this (as Craig Ringer does, above), since the error return value reliably identifies which one (syscall or C library function) is being referred to: "`-1` with `errno==EIO`" refers to a C library function, whereas "`-EIO`" refers to a syscall. Finally, [Linux man pages online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/) are the most up to date reference for Linux man pages.

Comment: @CraigRinger: To answer your final question: *"By using low-level I/O and `fsync()`/`fdatasync()` when the transaction size is a complete file; by using `mmap()`/`msync()` when the transaction size is a page-aligned record; and by using low-level I/O, `fdatasync()`, and multiple concurrent file descriptors (one descriptor and a thread per transaction) to the same file otherwise"*. The Linux-specific open file description locks (`fcntl()`, `F_OFD_`) are very useful with the last one.

Comment: @NominalAnimal So normal apps must remember all `write()`s since the last successful `fsync()` or `close()` and be able to repeat them on `-EIO`?  If the page is flagged `AS_EIO` does the app also need to re-read the page from disk to clear the flag? If it just tries to write a partial page I'd expect another `-EIO` result. I bet you'll find something approximating zero applications that get this right in the wild, especially given that the relevant man pages don't seem to say anything much about it.

Comment: @CraigRinger: What kind of normal apps are you referring to? For my workloads, I care about file integrity, not record integrity. This means my normal apps must report `write()`, `fsync()`, and `close()` failures (so that I, as the end user, know about it); and they must also do the `fsync()`. Most, but not all, current applications do not do the `fsync()` or even `fdatasync()`, and they do ignore `close()` and `fsync()` errors. This is bothersome to me, especially since upstream is typically uninterested in adding options for those checks (as "rare errors are not worth checking for").

Comment: @CraigRinger: For non-interactive tasks, logging and flagging (again, for user/admin action) is the most important part. (I for one check raw SMART attributes on my spinning disks to get indications of hardware failures -- I'm too poor for large SSDs --, and I'd love to have my services properly report any I/O errors too.)

Comment: @CraigRinger: For record-based stuff, I prefer to rely on remote replication instead, which reduces the problem back to "file integrity" (or table or db integrity). There are some applications that do have the necessary `fsync()` (often needs an option to enable) and do check it and `close()` for errors, but I don't have a list for you.  All utilities using gnulib `close_stream()` (coreutils) do check for `close()` errors; `dd` even has `conv=fsync` support. (So, use `dd` for important data!)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Checking for errors is nice, but just tells you "um, that didn't work, and now I don't know what the state is". Actually repeating the operation in a predictable manner and coping with any prior borkedness the previous failure caused... `dd` can be expected to do that but I'll be surprised if many others do.

Answer (score 22):

> Since the application's write() will have already returned without error, there seems to be no way to report an error back to the application.

I do not agree. `write` can return without error if the write is simply queued, but the error will be reported on the next operation that will require the actual writing on disk, that means on next `fsync`, possibly on a following write if the system decides to flush the cache and at least on last file close.

That is the reason why it is essential for application to test the return value of close to detect possible write errors.

If you really need to be able to do clever error processing you must assume that everything that was written since the last successful `fsync` **may** have failed and that in all that at least something has failed.

Comment: Yeah, I think that nails it. This would indeed suggest that the application should re-do all its work since the last confirmed-successful `fsync()` or `close()` of the file if it gets an `-EIO` from `write()`, `fsync()` or `close()`. Well, that's fun.

Answer (score 2):

`write`(2) provides less than you expect. The man page is very open about the semantic of a successful `write()` call:

> A  successful return from `write()` does not make any guarantee that
>       data has been committed to disk. In fact, on some buggy implementations,
>       it does not even guarantee that space has successfully  been reserved
>       for the data. The only way to be sure is to call `fsync`(2) after you
>       are done writing all your data.

We can conclude that a successful `write()` merely means that the data has reached the kernel's buffering facilities. If persisting the buffer fails, a subsequent access to the file descriptor will return the error code. As last resort that may be `close()`. The man page of the `close`(2) system call contains the following sentence:

> It is quite possible that errors on a previous `write`(2) operation are
>       first reported at the final `close`().

If your application needs to persist data write away it has to use `fsync`/`fsyncdata` on a regular basis:

> `fsync()` transfers ("flushes") all modified in-core data of (i.e., modified
>       buffer cache pages for) the file referred to by the file descriptor fd
>       to the disk device  (or  other  permanent storage  device)  so 
>       that  all  changed  information  can be retrieved even after the
>       system crashed or was rebooted.  This includes writing through or
>       flushing a disk cache if  present. The  call  blocks  until the
>       device reports that the transfer has completed.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that `fsync()` is required. But *in the specific case where the kernel loses the pages due to an I/O error* will `fsync()` fail? Under what circumstances can it then succeed afterwards?

Comment: I don't know the kernel source either. Let's assume `fsync()` returns `-EIO` on I/O issues (What would it be good for otherwise?). So the database knows some of a previous write failed and could go into recover mode. Is this not what you want? What is the motivation of your last question? Do you want to know which write failed or recover the file descriptor for further use?

Comment: Ideally a DBMS will prefer not to enter crash recovery (kicking off all users and becoming temporarily inaccessible or at least read-only) if it can possibly avoid it. But even if the kernel could tell us "bytes 4096 to 8191 of fd X" it'd be hard to figure out what to (re)write there without pretty much doing crash recovery. So I guess the main question is whether there are any more innocent circumstances where `fsync()` may return `-EIO` where it *is* safe to retry, and if it's  possible to tell the difference.

Comment: Sure crash recovery is the last resort. But as you already said these issues are expected to be very very rare. Therefore, I don't see an issue with going into recovery on any `-EIO`. If each file descriptor is only used by one thread at a time, this thread could go back to the last `fsync()` and redo the `write()` calls. But still, if those `write()`s only writes part of a sector the unmodified part may still be corrupt.

Comment: You're right that going into crash recovery is likely reasonable. As for partly corrupt sectors, the DBMS (PostgreSQL) stores an image of the whole page the first time it touches it after any given checkpoint for just that reason, so it should be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the O_SYNC flag when you open the file. It ensures the data is written to the disk.

If this won't satisfy you, there will be nothing.

Comment: `O_SYNC` is a nightmare for performance. It means the application cannot do anything *else* while disk I/O is occurring unless it spawns off I/O threads. You might as well say that the buffered I/O interface is unsafe and everyone should use AIO. Surely silently-lost writes cannot be acceptable in buffered I/O?

Comment: (`O_DATASYNC` is only slightly better in that regard)

Comment: @CraigRinger You *should* use AIO if you have this need and need any sort of performance.  Or just use a DBMS; it handles everything for you.

Comment: @Demi The application here is a dbms (postgresql). I'm sure you can imagine that rewriting the entire application to use AIO instead of buffered I/O is not practical. Nor should it be necessary.

Answer (score -6):

Check the return value of close. close can fail whilst buffered writes appear to succeed.

Comment: Well, we hardly want to be `open()`ing and `close()`ing the file every few seconds. that's why we have `fsync()` ...