# Saving files programatically in ImDisk's RAM DISK is not faster

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, ram, hard-drive

I have created a 256MB RAM Disk using [ImDisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/), and compared reading/writing speeds of the HDD and Ram Disk with the simple benchmark software [CrystalDiskMark](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/). CrystalDiskMark shows the RAM Disk is 10 times faster than the HDD, as it would be expected.

However, I tried saving data *programmatically* to the RAM Disk and HDD, expecting the RAM Disk to be faster, and the time taken is the same for both.

I wrote the following code in Java, created a JAR executable, and ran the executable in the HDD and Ram Disk. This code creates a 16x16 black image, saves 100 different PNG file copies of it locally, and prints in the terminal the time taken to save each file, the average, and the total time.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SaveImageSpeedTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        long n = 100;
        long total_time = 0;
        for(long i=0; i<n; i++) {
            try {
                long time = System.nanoTime();
                ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", new File(i+".png"));
                time = System.nanoTime()-time;
                total_time += time;
                System.out.println((i+1)+"/"+n+" - "+"Time: "+(time/1000000L)+" ms");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SaveImageSpeedTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        long average_time = total_time/n;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total time: "+(total_time/1000000L)+" ms");
        System.out.println("Average time: "+(average_time/1000000L)+" ms");
    }
}
```

How is this possible? Why isn't it faster, if the benchmark shows the RAM Disk is 10 times faster? I also tried saving data with a C++ executable and again, the times were the same.

**Edit 1:** By changing RAM Disk's format from NTFS to FAT, I get almost twice more speed, but it should be 10 times more.

**Edit 2:** I tried different image sizes and even making random images (to avoid caché data). Always the same results: Ram DISK is barely twice as fast.

Comment: That suggests that the disk is not the slowest component of the process.

Comment: If you're testing I/O, just allocate a big buffer and pass it to a write system call.  No need for any computation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write to a file, it [does not yet mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705454/does-linux-guarantee-the-contents-of-a-file-is-flushed-to-disc-after-close) that the data is actually written to a disk. Operating Systems typically use buffer cache to [defer writes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html#NOTES) to the device.

So, your benchmark basically measures the performance of image encoding plus writing to a buffer cache. If you want to measure actual device I/O, the performance test should at least involve [`FileChannel.force`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#force(boolean)) (which calls [`fsync`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) under the hood).

Besides that, exclude image encoding from the benchmark, as it also may take significant amount of time.